# rare characters at the beginning openssl_private_encrypt

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, private-key

I have a tester page from my Broker, in the first section I include a certificate (.crt) file

> `MIIFETCCA/mgAwIBAgIUMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwM...`

and a second section with an encrypted string with my private key, the original string is "`f2e140eb-2b09-44ab-8504-87b25d81914c`", and the resulting encrypted string with my priv key is:

> `ugSMAsCQlIKIlQ17exIvSEqkA60eWcnF4AAEVJG3BP4hYcCc+DCKeeHur6X2ShbjYWoeugPJe7AecPO0JY9jG75R67jS1OLUeUkB7HZqXCSzPANKWjQ/vx+0O0PlHHcWI24aUFCSiA2iuNXcssIbt2uJAChegXa7XKgNXxDJm+o=`

there is a button with label "Decipher", when a press it, I obtain:

> `�����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������f2e140eb-2b09-44ab-8504-87b25d81914c`

As you can see, I obtained the original string, but a lot of strange characters at the beginning, with this, I can not continue with the signature process.

Technical notes (maybe I am doing something wrong):
The first part (certificate:MIIFETC.....) is obtained with:

```
$filename="instancia_ope.cer";
$imgbinary = fread(fopen($filename, "r"), filesize($filename));
$certificadoInstancia64 = base64_encode($imgbinary);
```

and the string encrypted with my priv key (ugSMAsCQlIKI......) with:

```
$llave_priv = file_get_contents("i.pem");  //i.pem is my private key file
$plaintext = "f2e140eb-2b09-44ab-8504-87b25d81914c";
openssl_private_encrypt($plaintext, $encrypted, $llave_priv);
$reto = base64_encode($encrypted);
```

I obtained the i.pem file from the .key file with

```
openssl pkcs8 -inform DER -in instancia_ope.key -out i.pem
```

Is there any error in my procedure? I asked my Broker what the decipher button does, but I have not received answer.

Comment: maybe obvious to say, a successful test would output, ONLY the f2e140eb-2b09-44ab-8504-87b25d81914c string

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have retrieved the raw result from a decrypt option. However, looking at your result, that result was not created by a PKCS#1 v2.1 compatible encryption. This probably means there is something wrong with the encryption procedure.

Comment: the private key is in PKCS8 standard, in DER format. Why you mention PKCS#2.1?

Comment: I even tried with another distribution of Linux (Ubuntu), thinking that maybe the configuration of openssl is wrong, but not, the same result in CentOS and Ubuntu

Comment: Do you know another openssl library for php that uses the .key format directly? maybe there is a mistrake in my transformation from .key to .pem.

Comment: Oops, that should be PKCS#1 v2.1, just a moment

Comment: The private key is ok if you manage to decrypt into anything useful.

Comment: maybe I should use openssl_sign, what do you think? I tried but gives me a garbage string, I use: $data="f2e140eb-2b09-44ab-8504-87b25d81914c";
openssl_sign($data, $signature, $pkeyid);
$reto22 = base64_encode($signature);   //pkeyid is got with openssl_get_privatekey from the pem key file

Comment: Looks like it was signed rather than encrypted, with ver 1.5 block type 1 padding.

Comment: Are you saying I am obtaining the same result as with openssl_sign? I tested with it and a different string is obtained. My confusion is why encrypt with private key (openssl_private_encrypt) is different than signing (openssl_sign), in both I am using my private key

Comment: @user1873420 it depends on the library which padding mode is used. Basically, *there is no such thing* as encryption with a private key if you keep to PKCS#1 v2.1 padding modes. The only logical result is that you get the same result as when you are signing, but your results may vary. To be sure, use "NoPadding" and do the padding yourself. That should be relatively safe operation to implement yourself (although I would throw some unit tests against the format). To be sure, please supply us the output of the functions in hexadecimals instead of characters.

Comment: Not even a vote up after all that trouble, thank you for not caring.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your broker does plain textbook RSA decryption, not PKCS#1 padded RSA like OpenSSL does by default. Therefore the brokers test application does not remove the padding and you get a padded plaintext block as a result.

You can try to encrypt without any random padding by using `OPENSSL_NO_PADDING` as optional fourth argument to [openssl_private_encrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-private-encrypt.php):

```
openssl_private_encrypt($plaintext, $encrypted, $llave_priv, OPENSSL_NO_PADDING);
```

Note that using [unpadded plain textbook RSA is inherently insecure](http://www.di.ens.fr/~pnguyen/pub_BoJoNg00.htm) in most circumstances. In general, RSA should be used with a secure random padding mechanism, such as [PKCS#1 2.1 OAEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_asymmetric_encryption_padding). Otherwise there are a lot of cryptographic security issues, such as the complete interchangeability of decryption and signing, [easy attacks against the mathematical structure](http://rdist.root.org/2009/10/06/why-rsa-encryption-padding-is-critical/) including [malleability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malleability_%28cryptography%29), and the lack of [semantic security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_security). These may or may not be applicable to your situation, since you seem to essentially use an ad-hoc RSA signature protocol.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I tried with OPENSSL_NO_PADDING and is not generating anything, Reto comes to be empty.

Comment: In encryption we use the public key of the receiver, why the term private term in the function openssl_private_encrypt? seems contradictory or confused to me. When I use private key, I am signing something wiht my private key. looks like this function would give the same result as openssl_sign(), I tried both and gave me different output. Because the function open_private_encrypt has private and encrypt, I dont know if it is for encrypting or for siging, what is this function for???????

Answer (score 0):

Probably something with the database collation.
I had the same problem.
The collation was something with: `SWEDISH_CI`
then changed it into: `UTF8_GENERAL_CI`

Works fine now